# IndexOutOfBoundsException when working with arrayList

Tags: java, algorithm, permutation, indexoutofboundsexception

The task is described here [Creating combination of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22388138/creating-combination-of-numbers) or here [Permutations of integer array algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406245/permutations-of-integer-array-algorithm).

I decided to solve this problem in this way:
From first number to the last check the possibility of permutation:

Create arraLists of the first permutation and of the difference

`del1` and `rem0`

`Bool` is an object with two parametrs: `st` - start and `end`

It`s new permutation

I create new Bool, that at the start have the same start and end, like it is one number. So, we cant use this number anymore before starting new permutation with another start number. And we remove it from the list of numbers `rem` . And start create permutation with checking.

```
for (int index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
            List<Integer> del1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            List<Integer> rem0 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i = 0; i < del.length; i++) {
                del1.add(del[i]);
            }


            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                rem0.add(arr[i]);
            }


            Bool start = new Bool(arr[index], arr[index]);
            rem0.remove(index);
            check(start, del1, rem0);


        }
```

Checking:

`ucet` - number of "good" permutations, if the difference of new permutation is the same, as the first, it is "good".

So, I for the ending number I add difference number and if it = number in the list of possible numbers  - I add this number to the end of permutation, remove it from the list of possible and remove difference prom the list of differences(by creating new lists).
And then continue creating.

```
private static void check(Bool start, List<Integer> del2, List<Integer> rem) {
        if (del2.isEmpty()) {
            ucet++;


        }

        for (int index = 0; index<rem.size(); index++) {

             for (int i = 0; i<del2.size(); i++) {

                if(start.end+del2.get(i)==rem.get(index)){

            List<Integer> del3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            List<Integer> rem2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            del3=del2;rem2=rem;

            Bool con=new Bool(start.st,rem.get(index));

                    rem2.remove(index);
                    del3.remove(i);
                    check(con,del3,rem2);
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

But I have one bug, that I cant understand. Its `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. In the string `if(start.end+del2.get(i)==rem.get(index)){` .

And it causes `del2.get(i)`.

But the problem is, that `i<del2.size()`.

Can you help me to deal with it? Thanks

Comment: i < del2.size should be fine...?  paste your exception

Comment: I checked it with first permutation `1  4  2  5  7  6  9  8  3` and first difference `3 -2 3 2 -1 3 -1 -5 1`. Exception was `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2`

Comment: You are removing elements from the list that you are currently looping through

Comment: I suppose, when I create new lists, I am dealing with it, is`t it?

Answer (score 0):

You are removing entities from the list as you are looping through it, not good. You could try using while loop in conjunction with `iterable.hasNext()` or instead of `rem0.remove(index)` do `rem0.set(index, null)`.